# Controller Variable undefined when fetching from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does on go about getting a variable that is the result of a factory in Angular? I keep getting undefined when i try to get results from my factory.

For instance in my factory i have

```
angular.module('MyApp.services', [])
.factory('ReportService', ['$http', '$window', '$upload', 'AuthService', function ($http, $window, $upload, AuthService) {
    return {
        findAll: function (criteria) {
            criteria = criteria || [];
            return $http.get(BASE_URL + '/ajax.php?action=reports.all&' + criteria.join('&'))
        },
        getAll: function (criteria){
         return $http.get(BASE_URL + '/ajax.php?action=reports.all&' + criteria.join('&'))
         .success(function(data, status) {
          return data;
          });
        }        }
}])
```

Then in my controller

```
controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$compile', 'CartoDBService', 'ReportService', 'toaster', '$modal', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $compile, ReportService, toaster, $modal, $rootScope) {

     var reportSearchParams = ['graded=on'];

     var cat = ReportService.findAll(reportSearchParams);
     cat.then(function(data) {
         $scope.students = data.data;//don't forget "this" in the service
     });
     console.log($scope.students);//returns unidentified
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code ??

Comment: $http is asynchronous. You can't log the response until it is received. Move the log statement into the `then()`

Comment: How do i get the result to a var outside the asynchronous function